# Converting angular velocity to quaternion in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, quaternions

I need the angular velocity expressed as a quaternion for updating the quaternion every frame with the following expression in OpenCV:

```
q(k)=q(k-1)*qwt;
```

My angular velocity is

```
Mat w;  //1x3
```

I would like to obtain a quaternion form of the angles

```
Mat qwt;   //1x4
```

I couldn't find information about this, any ideas?

Comment: A quaternion represents a rotation or an orientation. The angular velocity is the derivative of it. It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I guess he wants to express the angular velocity as a qaternion to update the quaternion value as this product:
q(k)=q(k-1)*qwt

Comment: Being qwt the angular velocity expressed as a quaternion

Comment: Yes, thats it! I want to update quaternion value each frame using the angular velocity.

Comment: Alright, then if you use angular velocity each frame be careful because w should be multiplied by time between frames.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand properly you want to pass from this [Axis Angle form to a quaternion](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/angleToQuaternion/index.htm).

As shown in the link, first you need to calculate the module of the angular velocity (multiplied by delta(t) between frames), and then apply the formulas.

A sample function for this would be

```cpp
// w is equal to angular_velocity*time_between_frames
void quatFromAngularVelocity(Mat& qwt, const Mat& w)
{
    const float x = w.at<float>(0);
    const float y = w.at<float>(1);
    const float z = w.at<float>(2);
    const float angle = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);  // module of angular velocity

    if (angle > 0.0) // the formulas from the link
    {
        qwt.at<float>(0) = x*sin(angle/2.0f)/angle;
        qwt.at<float>(1) = y*sin(angle/2.0f)/angle;
        qwt.at<float>(2) = z*sin(angle/2.0f)/angle;
        qwt.at<float>(3) = cos(angle/2.0f);
    } else    // to avoid illegal expressions
    {
        qwt.at<float>(0) = qwt.at<float>(0)=qwt.at<float>(0)=0.0f;
        qwt.at<float>(3) = 1.0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be you have made a mistake in the following line? `qwt.at<float>(0)=qwt.at<float>(0)=qwt.at<float>(0)=0.0f;` You set the same component over and over again.

Answer (score 4):

Almost every transformation regarding quaternions, 3D space, etc is gathered at this [website](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/quaternions/index.htm).

You will find time derivatives for quaternions also.

I find it useful the explanation of the physical meaning of a quaternion, which can be seen as an axis angle where

```
a = angle of rotation
x,y,z = axis of rotation.
```

Then the conversion uses:

```
q = cos(a/2) + i ( x * sin(a/2)) + j (y * sin(a/2)) + k ( z * sin(a/2))
```

[Here](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/quaternions/geometric/axisAngle/index.htm) is explained thoroughly.

Hope this helped to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

One little trick to go with this and get rid of those cos and sin functions. The time derivative of a quaternion q(t) is:

dq(t)/dt = 0.5 * x(t) * q(t)

Where, if the angular velocity is {w0, w1, w2} then x(t) is a quaternion of {0, w0, w1, w2}. See David H Eberly's book section 10.5 for proof

Comment: Is your quaternion {x,y,z,w} or {w,x,y,z}?